# remove the entire group when there are some certain observations in the group

Tags: r, dataset

I have a dataset like this

```
df <- data.frame(group = c(rep(1,3),rep(2,2), rep(3,2),rep(4,3),rep(5, 2)), score = c(0, 10, 22, 44, 6, 5, 20, 1, 2, 0, 1,5))

   group score
1      1     0
2      1    10
3      1    22
4      2    44
5      2     6
6      3     5
7      3    20
8      4     1
9      4     2
10     4     0
11     5     1
12     5     5
```

I want to remove the entire group if there are 0 or 1 in the score, the output should look like this:

```
   group score
1      2    44
2      2     6
3      3     5
4      3    20
```

Is there a good way to realized this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a filter on the rows of `df`:

```
df[!df$group %in% unique(df$group[df$score %in% c(0, 1)]),]
#   group score
# 4     2    44
# 5     2     6
# 6     3     5
# 7     3    20
```

The filter uses `%in%` to check if a each row's group is in the set of groups associated with a score of 0 or 1, removing all such rows.

Comment: Nice. `data.table` variant for fun: `df[,if(!any(score %in% c(0,1))) .SD, by=group]`